# 403 Forbidden error during the installation of dashboard of OpenStack

Tags: openstack

I have tried to install the dashboard service for my test-used OpenStack instance following the offical guidance.
When I tried to visit the URL provided in the installation document, an error with code of 403 was encountered.

The content of white page:
 `Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.`

I checked the error log of the Apache service of controller node. Becuase I refresh the page with multiple times, it occurs to give some error message more than 1 time but with similar content:

```
[Tue Aug 08 21:15:56.500423 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 1135243:tid 140130052388608] [client 10.2.3.5:59824] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py
[Tue Aug 08 21:15:57.214297 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 1135243:tid 140130060781312] [client 10.2.3.5:59824] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py
[Tue Aug 08 21:15:57.483349 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 1135243:tid 140130069174016] [client 10.2.3.5:59824] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py
[Tue Aug 08 21:15:57.654507 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 1135243:tid 140130077566720] [client 10.2.3.5:59824] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py
[Tue Aug 08 21:15:57.832566 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 1135243:tid 140130085959424] [client 10.2.3.5:59824] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py
```

The file `/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py` is exists. Because the original `/etc/httpd/conf.d/openstack-dashboard.conf` file redirect the "/dashboard" to a file in the folder `/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/`, but that folder is NOT exist (The webpage cannot be visited, but 403 forbidden error), so I suspected that the aim of the action is to redirect the request to a WSGI program, then I list all files under the folder `/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard` and found a file with filename `wsgi.py`, therefore I replaced the redirect path to `wsgi.py`. Then I restart `httpd` and `memcached` services and verify the result, but still with **Forbidden Error**.

So I also suspected that the problem maybe caused by the permission of folder `/usr/share/openstack-dashboard`, so with the aim of testing, I execute the following command to set the perimission `777`:

```bash
sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/share/openstack-dashboard
```

Then I restart `httpd` and `memcached` services and verify the result, but still with **Forbidden Error**.

So I want to know why it still failed to start the dashboard?
It will be appreciated if you can provide helps.

---

##### Environment of host

### OS: Rocky Linux 8.8

The content of file `/etc/openstack-dashboard/local_settings` is:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# NOTE: The default values of the settings are defined in
# openstack_dashboard/defaults.py. Previously most available settings
# were listed in this example file, but it is no longer true.
# For available settings, see openstack_dashboard/defaults.py and
# the horizon setting reference found at
# https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/latest/configuration/settings.html.
#
# Django related settings and HORIZON_CONFIG still exist here.
# Keep in my mind that they will be revisit in upcoming releases.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

import os

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


from openstack_dashboard.settings import HORIZON_CONFIG

DEBUG = False
OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_MULTIDOMAIN_SUPPORT = True
OPENSTACK_API_VERSIONS = {
    "identity": 3,
    "image": 2,
    "volume": 3,
}
OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_DEFAULT_DOMAIN = "Default"
OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_DEFAULT_ROLE = "admin"
OPENSTACK_NEUTRON_NETWORK = {
    'enable_router': False,
    'enable_quotas': False,
    'enable_distributed_router': False,
    'enable_ha_router': False,
    'enable_fip_topology_check': False,
}

# This setting controls whether or not compression is enabled. Disabling
# compression makes Horizon considerably slower, but makes it much easier
# to debug JS and CSS changes
#COMPRESS_ENABLED = not DEBUG

# This setting controls whether compression happens on the fly, or offline
# with `python manage.py compress`
# See https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#offline-compression
# for more information
#COMPRESS_OFFLINE = not DEBUG

# If horizon is running in production (DEBUG is False), set this
# with the list of host/domain names that the application can serve.
# For more information see:
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Set SSL proxy settings:
# Pass this header from the proxy after terminating the SSL,
# and don't forget to strip it from the client's request.
# For more information see:
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header
#SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# If Horizon is being served through SSL, then uncomment the following two
# settings to better secure the cookies from security exploits
#CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
#SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

# If provided, a "Report Bug" link will be displayed in the site header
# which links to the value of this setting (ideally a URL containing
# information on how to report issues).
#HORIZON_CONFIG["bug_url"] = "http://bug-report.example.com"

# Show backdrop element outside the modal, do not close the modal
# after clicking on backdrop.
#HORIZON_CONFIG["modal_backdrop"] = "static"

# Specify a regular expression to validate user passwords.
#HORIZON_CONFIG["password_validator"] = {
#    "regex": '.*',
#    "help_text": _("Your password does not meet the requirements."),
#}

# Turn off browser autocompletion for forms including the login form and
# the database creation workflow if so desired.
#HORIZON_CONFIG["password_autocomplete"] = "off"

# Setting this to True will disable the reveal button for password fields,
# including on the login form.
#HORIZON_CONFIG["disable_password_reveal"] = False

LOCAL_PATH = '/tmp'

# Set custom secret key:
# You can either set it to a specific value or you can let horizon generate a
# default secret key that is unique on this machine, e.i. regardless of the
# amount of Python WSGI workers (if used behind Apache+mod_wsgi): However,
# there may be situations where you would want to set this explicitly, e.g.
# when multiple dashboard instances are distributed on different machines
# (usually behind a load-balancer). Either you have to make sure that a session
# gets all requests routed to the same dashboard instance or you set the same
# SECRET_KEY for all of them.
SECRET_KEY='3874b8b780e8ea963f89'

# We recommend you use memcached for development; otherwise after every reload
# of the django development server, you will have to login again. To use
# memcached set CACHES to something like below.
# For more information, see
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/.
#CACHES = {
#    'default': {
#        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
#        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
#    },
#}

CACHES = {
    'default': {
         'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
         'LOCATION': 'controller:11211',
    }
}

# If you use ``tox -e runserver`` for developments,then configure
# SESSION_ENGINE to django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies
# as shown below:
#SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'

# Send email to the console by default
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
# Or send them to /dev/null
#EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend'

# Configure these for your outgoing email host
#EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.my-company.com'
#EMAIL_PORT = 25
#EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'djangomail'
#EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'top-secret!'

OPENSTACK_HOST = "controller"
OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_URL = "http://%s:5000/identity/v3" % "10.2.3.4"

# The timezone of the server. This should correspond with the timezone
# of your entire OpenStack installation, and hopefully be in UTC.
TIME_ZONE = "Asia/Shanghai"

# Change this patch to the appropriate list of tuples containing
# a key, label and static directory containing two files:
# _variables.scss and _styles.scss
#AVAILABLE_THEMES = [
#    ('default', 'Default', 'themes/default'),
#    ('material', 'Material', 'themes/material'),
#    ('example', 'Example', 'themes/example'),
#]

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    # When set to True this will disable all logging except
    # for loggers specified in this configuration dictionary. Note that
    # if nothing is specified here and disable_existing_loggers is True,
    # django.db.backends will still log unless it is disabled explicitly.
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    # If apache2 mod_wsgi is used to deploy OpenStack dashboard
    # timestamp is output by mod_wsgi. If WSGI framework you use does not
    # output timestamp for logging, add %(asctime)s in the following
    # format definitions.
    'formatters': {
        'console': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s'
        },
        'operation': {
            # The format of "%(message)s" is defined by
            # OPERATION_LOG_OPTIONS['format']
            'format': '%(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            # Set the level to "DEBUG" for verbose output logging.
            'level': 'DEBUG' if DEBUG else 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'console',
        },
        'operation': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'operation',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'horizon': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'horizon.operation_log': {
            'handlers': ['operation'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'openstack_dashboard': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'novaclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'cinderclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'keystoneauth': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'keystoneclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'glanceclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'neutronclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'swiftclient': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'oslo_policy': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'openstack_auth': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        # Logging from django.db.backends is VERY verbose, send to null
        # by default.
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'requests': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'urllib3': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'chardet.charsetprober': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'iso8601': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'scss': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}

# 'direction' should not be specified for all_tcp/udp/icmp.
# It is specified in the form.
SECURITY_GROUP_RULES = {
    'all_tcp': {
        'name': _('All TCP'),
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '1',
        'to_port': '65535',
    },
    'all_udp': {
        'name': _('All UDP'),
        'ip_protocol': 'udp',
        'from_port': '1',
        'to_port': '65535',
    },
    'all_icmp': {
        'name': _('All ICMP'),
        'ip_protocol': 'icmp',
        'from_port': '-1',
        'to_port': '-1',
    },
    'ssh': {
        'name': 'SSH',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '22',
        'to_port': '22',
    },
    'smtp': {
        'name': 'SMTP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '25',
        'to_port': '25',
    },
    'dns': {
        'name': 'DNS',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '53',
        'to_port': '53',
    },
    'http': {
        'name': 'HTTP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '80',
        'to_port': '80',
    },
    'pop3': {
        'name': 'POP3',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '110',
        'to_port': '110',
    },
    'imap': {
        'name': 'IMAP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '143',
        'to_port': '143',
    },
    'ldap': {
        'name': 'LDAP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '389',
        'to_port': '389',
    },
    'https': {
        'name': 'HTTPS',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '443',
        'to_port': '443',
    },
    'smtps': {
        'name': 'SMTPS',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '465',
        'to_port': '465',
    },
    'imaps': {
        'name': 'IMAPS',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '993',
        'to_port': '993',
    },
    'pop3s': {
        'name': 'POP3S',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '995',
        'to_port': '995',
    },
    'ms_sql': {
        'name': 'MS SQL',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '1433',
        'to_port': '1433',
    },
    'mysql': {
        'name': 'MYSQL',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '3306',
        'to_port': '3306',
    },
    'rdp': {
        'name': 'RDP',
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '3389',
        'to_port': '3389',
    },
}

# Help URL can be made available for the client. To provide a help URL, edit the
# following attribute to the URL of your choice.
#HORIZON_CONFIG["help_url"] = "http://openstack.mycompany.org"
```